# Wordpress short code to display all child page by parents ID

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, shortcode

I'm working on a short code for loop through parents ID and display all child page, but I'm not quite sure how to make the loop and make it more custom.

Here's my code:
add_shortcode( 'home-page-listing', 'get_list' );

```
function get_list( $atts ) {
    ob_start();
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
            'ids' => ''
    ), $atts );
    if($atts['ids']!='')
    {
        $id_array = explode(',',$atts['ids']);
        $homePages = new WP_Query( array(
                'post_type' => 'page',
                'post__in'=>$id_array,
                'order' => 'ASC',
                'orderby' => 'post__in',
                'posts_per_page' => -1
        ) );
        if ($homePages->have_posts()){?>
            <div class="">

                <?php while ( $homePages->have_posts() ) : $homePages->the_post(); ?>
                     //here's html template code
                <?php endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```

Right now **I can use `[home-page-listing id=1,2,3,4]` to display all select page ID**, but I would like to make like this:

```
[home-page-listing parentID=4]
```

loop through all child page and display to the font, instead go check all the page id to display.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

it's simple used **`post_parent`** Arguments of  **`WP_Query`**. Please check below example

```
$homePages = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'post_parent'=>$parentID,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'orderby' => 'parent',
    'posts_per_page' => -1
) );
```

For more information of WP_Query [click here](https://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/)

Comment: Thank you so much for help @Ankur Bhadania, I will tried to add it in these couple days.